# IOS/objective-c: Best practice to maintain state across IOS phone and server running PHP

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, cookies

I have an IOS app that syncs with a server running php and MYSQL on the back end.

After connecting with the server, I have been setting a session variable to maintain state.  Session variables, as I understand it, reside as cookies on the IOS device.  I set one as the userid to avoid sending the userid back and forth with every request.

Howevever, the problem is my HOST does not make it possible to change the length of the session variable cookies and they expire relatively soon i.e. in a few hours.  I would like the app to stay more or less permanently logged into the server.

Do most people send a userid back and forth with every API call or are session variables the right approach and I should find a way to make them persistent perhaps by logging in in the background whenever the app awakes.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

When using sessions in PHP, you actually have many ways you can store the session identifier -- cookies being one of them. If you are curious to use a robust session library, Laravel keeps that component isolated in case someone wants to use it outside of Laravel (https://github.com/illuminate/session).

In your particular case (given the server limitations), the approach that will be easier to manage and more decoupled is to pass everything you need with the API call each time. In this way, you never have to worry about maintaining state between the client and server and your code will be more flexible (i.e. maybe creating an android client in the future.)

Comment: After a successful logon, I usually keep a session variable "successful logon" as a security measure and check it before allowing response.  Any suggestion on how to prevent unauthorized calls to the API?  IE would I include some sort of security token or salt the user info?